# javascript it dosen't work push() in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi i don't understand this situation. i want to insert data to Forms array.
Forms[0] data is string as "A". i want to insert data Forms[0]. for example, when i run code,
i want to result

Before:

```
 Forms:[{
    "name":"A" 
  }]
```

After: ->>i want to result!!

```
 Forms:[{
    "name":"A",
    "Layout":[{
        "a":a
     }]
    }
 ]
```

Code:

```
var Forms=[];
var FormsData={};
var Vidgets=[];
var VidgetData={};
var layoutData={};
var GridSeq=0;

for(var i=0;i<allForm.length;i++){
            FormsData.NAME=allForm[i].title;
            Forms.push(FormsData.NAME);
        }
        var Zones=0;
        for(var i=0;i<allForm.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<allForm[i].getChildren().length;j++){
                //console.log(allForm[i].getChildren()[j].nbZones);
                Zones=allForm[i].getChildren()[j].nbZones;
                GridSeq++;
                layoutData.Zones=Zones;
                layoutData.GridSeq=GridSeq;
                layout.push(layoutData);
                Forms[i].Layout=layout[j];---->it dosen't work
                layoutData={};
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are using an array as an object. Use `{ }` and not `[ ]`

Comment: what do you mean by before and after?

Comment: @jhyap before is I don't run the code, and then I run the code that is after.

Comment: So what is the result that you are expecting to get?

Comment: @jhyap i want to result is Forms:[{
    "name":"A",
    "Layout":[
        "a":a
     ]
    }
 ]

Comment: The problem is that your before and after are not valid Javascript data.

Comment: Arrays don't have `key: value` pairs, only object do.

Comment: @Barmar sorry my mistake i am correct!

Comment: you already getting the result you want since you said after you run the code and you get the result...

Comment: @jhyap Expression did not speak English well enough. immediately after the result is what I want.

Comment: you can use Forms[i] = FormsData.NAME;

Comment: Try 'Forms[i].Layout = layoutData'. what is the error? what that 'allForm' variable contains??

Comment: everybody thanks!!!Sorry, i did not get a good representation of English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Json Which you are passing is not correct**

```
var Forms={name:'', Layout:''}
```

and then pass it like

`Forms.push({name:FormsData.NAME, Layout: {'a':layoutData} });`